# Is it asking too much of canvas to redraw everything inside of the game loop?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[I've started a Breakout game in Canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/gRpzW/).

At the moment, I've only coded the display of the blocks and player.

When the game needs to update itself (every 10ms or so) it will need to call `draw()` which is currently going to repaint the entire canvas based on the current state of player, blocks and ball.

Its performance is starting to become an issue.

Is it never a good idea to repaint the entire canvas per frame? Should I be altering my code to only paint the sections which are changing?

Comment: Why are you refreshing the canvas at 100fps?  I think 30fps would be enough..

Comment: @BlueRaja Don't know, I just chose that number when writing the question. I'm a canvas/game development novice.

Comment: I ended up [finishing it](https://rawgithub.com/alexanderdickson/Outbreak/master/index.html) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off: Yes, altering your code to only paint the sections that are changing may help lots, but you should always be testing specific improvements with your own code as the performance of any one optimization varies by app (sometimes greatly).

But its not only *drawing* that can cause slowness. Make sure, for instance, that you aren't recomputing/reconstructing anything in your draw loop that never changes.

Also, if you have a lot of objects, don't set `fillStyle` unless you have to, which means there's an optimization to be had by setting the fill to one color, drawing all the objects of that color, and then setting the second fill color, etc.

Finally, I'd suggest writing your entire game (or most of it) and *then* going back and doing optimizations.

There are loads of optimizations to be had with Canvas. I've recently begun a guidebook on game-related performance enhancements, hopefully it'll be done by the year's end.

Comment: This sums up the idea best in my opinion. Try to not worry too much about optimizations at first - it's not smart to completely ignore it, but don't worry _too much. Other JS performance bottlenecks to keep in mind are functions calls (doing lots of these is slower than inlining, also Math.round vs. using bit shifts to round, etc.), reading things from DOM elements (never do it if you can avoid, always store in a variable) - I wrote some tips here: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/04/30/optimizing-javascript-for-extreme-performance-and-low-memory-consumption/

Answer (score 5):

You will have to try to be sure, but I disagree with both answers here. In my simple tests, attempting to clear and redraw just particular regions of the canvas produces **slightly worse performance**, not better.

You can see my test here: http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_sprites_canvas.html

This depends on your needs, however. If you have hundreds of items that do not need to be updated and only a small portion of your canvas changes each frame, perhaps clearing and redrawing only that section will be good.

Comment: Interesting results... I found the completely opposite when testing a similar approach of rendering. The main difference I see with mine was that I used the canvas' image data directly - getImageData and putImageData vs. drawing from the image as you're doing.

Comment: @Jani Very surprising, as my tests show that `get/putImageData` are [gobs slower](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_copy_benchmark.html).

Comment: I was draving considerably simpler images though, so perhaps that had an effect on how it performs

Answer (score 0):

> Is it never a good idea to repaint the entire canvas per frame?

No, sometimes it's a perfectly good idea

> Its performance is starting to become an issue

But not then.

That said, though, your code is not that complicated and there's nothing to cause obvious massive slowdowns.  How are you measuring its performance?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was testing in a Chrome with about 15 tabs open so that is most likely a factor in the slowdown I was seeing :)

Answer (score 0):

First I'd take all this out of init():

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

There's no point dealing with that every millisecond!

Secondly, look at this: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Thanks, but `init()` would be called once. `draw()` is the method that updates the canvas.